# "I won't be home for three hours."

Tags: meaning

The sentence **I won't be home for the next three hours** means that I won't be staying at home for a period of time of three hours in a row (but I can be home, for example, for 2 hours, leave, and come back home after 5 minutes) , or that I will be outside my home for a period of time of three consecutive hours? Or can it mean both?

Comment: It's entirely context-dependent whether OP's text means won't *remain* or won't *arrive* for the next three hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people would expect that you mean you won't be home for all or most of that time. If you wanted to convey that you *might* not be around during that time, you might say "I'll be in and out for the next three hours".

Comment: Or "I'll be home three hours from now".